# rsync endless creation of recursing directories

Tags: rsync

I've used `rsync` a bit before, but I'm a bit baffled with this.  I've just started exploring WSL (installed Linux is Ubuntu 20.04) and this is one of the main things I'm interested in setting up.

This is my command (all one line):

```
rsync --progress --modify-window=1 --update --recursive --times 
--link-dest=/mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T154600 
/mnt/d/My\ Documents/ /mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T154600
```

(I later tried without the trailing slash of `/mnt/d/My\ Documents/`: same result).

So I'm trying to `rsync` my directory D:\My Documents. Simple.  /mnt/f is an external hard drive formatted NTFS.

I'm using these options because over the past few days I've started exploring WSL and found that some switches/options suggestions for using `rsync` seem to cause problems. I had previously done a few trivial tests with `rsync`, using some 20 files, with no problems: snapshotting and use of hard links verified by checking, using `df`, the "Available" disk space before and after a 2nd snapshot after modifying one of the files.

More importantly, none of those options seems particularly harmful or complex, having looked at the `rsync --help`.

**The baffling result:**
The "My Documents" folder in question has a volume of about 5 GB. So I left `rsync` doing its thing and expected to finish in maybe 10 minutes.

After an hour I came back and it was still working. When I examined the HD I found that under F:\Backups\rsync\My Documents\snapshot2021-02-21T154600\ there were all the directories under D:\My Documents... but also two directories which shouldn't be there: another "My Documents", and another "snapshot2021-02-21T154600". Looking under the latter I found all the directories under D:\My Documents again... plus, yes, yet another "My Documents" and yet another "snapshot2021-02-21T154600"!!  ... and looking under the latter... yes, it was recursing down endlessly.

Instead of being 5 GB, the total volume of /mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T154600 was currently 70 GB! I'm pretty sure that if I hadn't interrupted things it would have filled out the entire HD.

Of course, one thought that occurred to me is that all might not be what it seems: what appear to be "recursing directories" might possibly be hard links that just make it look that way.

I'm also aware that there's no point in setting `--link-dest` the first time you run `rsync` (i.e. it's only subsequent snapshots which then use that location to create hard links). But I did that before, with the test runs, and it never caused any problems. I don't see why it should create any problems.

In any event, something has gone horribly wrong, and I don't understand why. Can anyone suggest the problem (and solution)?

***Edit***
It ***appears*** that by putting slashes at the end of every path here the problem doesn't arise. I.e. it becomes

```
rsync --progress --modify-window=1 --update --recursive --times 
--link-dest=/mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T154600/ 
/mnt/d/My\ Documents/ /mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My\ Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T154600/
```

... is this consistent with any written rules or acquired knowledge about `rsync`? Should I delete this question or leave it up for anyone encountering similar problems?

On the face of it, if this is indeed the solution to the problem, I would have thought the `rsync` functionality is slightly off: surely making the mistake (if such it be) of not having a trailing slash shouldn't result in the phenomenon I describe. Of course, this may be a quirk due to the specific context (WSL): beyond my paygrade.

Comment: why are you using  `--modify-window=1` if there is no ms windows FAT filesystem involved ?

Comment: According to --help that is for "set the accuracy for mod-time comparisons". I had no idea it only applied to FAT systems. I have basically just copied these options from a page where someone said they had managed to get rsync working under WSL.

Comment: i will quote from the manual `--modify-window
When comparing two timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps as being equal if they differ by no more than the modify-window value. This is normally 0 (for an exact match), but you may find it useful to set this to a larger value in some situations. In particular, when transferring to or from an MS Windows FAT filesystem (which represents times with a 2-second resolution), --modify-window=1 is useful (allowing times to differ by up to 1 second).`

Comment: OK thanks for that. I'll bear in mind the thought of omitting that option in future. I'm tending to think it is not germane to the main issue...

Comment: you already resolved the main issue, i would suggest the use of `""` to increase the readability of the paths, ex: `"/mnt/f/Backups/rsync/My Documents/snapshot2021-02-21T154600/"`

Comment: Thanks, yes, that seems sensible. I'll experiment with and without trailing slashes inside the quotes. Incidentally, I just ran another snapshot without `--modify-window=1` and this seems to make things run marginally better (I'm having multiple read-permission problems, despite everything being chmodded to be readable by all... but that's for another question).